# Evaluate function over set if intervals

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I have two sets of numbers

xl=linspace(0.,1,1000)
xu=linspace(0.,1,1000)+0.5

which should form pairwise intervals over which I want to run a polynomial function.
I want to store the resulting values for each interval, as lists within a list.

The only way I can think of is the following:

```
-Variables
xl=linspace(0.,1,1000)
xu=linspace(0.,1,1000)+0.5
M=[]-the list where the intervals are to be stored
Values=[] # The list where the output of the polynomial function will be stored.
       
      
class Interval:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

    def __repr__(self):
        return'[{},{}]'.format(self.left,self.right)   

def BuildIntervalFromLists(x,y): (builds the list of intervals)

     for i, j in zip(x, y):

                M.append(Interval(i,j))     
     return M

    def Polynomial(t): (The function)
    
    3*t**3-2*t**2-5*t-1
                  
def PolynomialFunction(x): (Function to run over all intervals)

    for k in x: # The intervals in sequence
        for l in k: # The numbers in each interval in sequence 
            Values.append([Polynomial(l)])
    return(Values)

BuildIntervalFromLists(xl,xu)

PolynomialFunction(M)
```

This, however, gives the error message that I can't run an iteration over an interval.

Is there any way of getting around this problem?
If not, is there a better approach?

Comment: [This might help you](https://blog.finxter.com/python-__iter__-magic-method/#:~:text=The%20Python%20__iter__,built%2Din%20iter()%20function.)

Comment: You're calling Polynomial with arguments like [.2, .7].  What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special method in python which is called ***getitem*** to reach an item inside of an object. You can simply define it as follows:

```
def __getitem__(self, position):
    
    return self.my_array[position]
```

As you can see I also define *my_array* variable inside the class. So the new class implementation will be like this:

```
class Interval:
 def __init__(self,left,right):
    self.left=left
    self.right=right
    self.my_array = [left,right]

 def __repr__(self):
    return'[{},{}]'.format(self.left,self.right)   

 def __getitem__(self, position):
    
    return self.my_array[position]
```

Now, you can see the variables inside of your class thanks to ***repr*** and you can iterate them by using ***getitem***

The overall code will be like this:

```
import numpy as np
xl=np.linspace(0.,1,1000)
xu=np.linspace(0.,1,1000)+0.5
M=[]
Values=[] # The list where the output of the polynomial function will be stored.
       
      
class Interval:
    def __init__(self,left,right):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
        self.my_array = [left,right]

    def __repr__(self):
        return'[{},{}]'.format(self.left,self.right)   
    
    def __getitem__(self, position):
        
        return self.my_array[position]

def BuildIntervalFromLists(x,y): 

    for i, j in zip(x, y):

                M.append(Interval(i,j))     
    return M

def Polynomial(t): 
    
    return 3*t**3-2*t**2-5*t-1
                  
def PolynomialFunction(x): 

    for k in x: # The intervals in sequence
        for l in k: # The numbers in each interval in sequence 
            Values.append([Polynomial(l)])
    return(Values)

BuildIntervalFromLists(xl,xu)
PolynomialFunction(M)
```

I hope it will solve your problem. Best

Comment: Wow, thank yo so much. Reading up on this, looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: Yo're welcome @Bronze. If it is the solution for you please mark it so people can use. Best!